# Can't able to Play RTMP Voice Stream in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, rtmp, live-streaming, exoplayer2.x, ant-media-server-sdk

When I stream Video with Audio I could able to play both Audio and Video in receiver side, When I stream Audio alone I Can't able to Play Audio in receiver side.

```
private void initializePlayer(String rtmpUrl) {
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean needNewPlayer = player == null;
    if (needNewPlayer) {

      boolean preferExtensionDecoders = intent.getBooleanExtra(PREFER_EXTENSION_DECODERS, false);
      @DefaultRenderersFactory.ExtensionRendererMode int extensionRendererMode =
              useExtensionRenderers()
                      ? (preferExtensionDecoders ? DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_PREFER
                      : DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_ON)
                      : DefaultRenderersFactory.EXTENSION_RENDERER_MODE_OFF;
      TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory =
              new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(BANDWIDTH_METER);
      trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);
      player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector, new DefaultLoadControl(),
              null, extensionRendererMode);
      player.addListener(this);

      eventLogger = new EventLogger(trackSelector);
      player.addListener(eventLogger);

      simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);
      player.setPlayWhenReady(shouldAutoPlay);
      debugViewHelper = new DebugTextViewHelper(player, debugTextView);
      debugViewHelper.start();
    }
    if (needNewPlayer || needRetrySource) {
      Uri[] uris;
      String[] extensions;

      uris = new Uri[1];
      uris[0] = Uri.parse(rtmpUrl);
      extensions = new String[1];
      extensions[0] = "";
      if (Util.maybeRequestReadExternalStoragePermission(this, uris)) {
        // The player will be reinitialized if the permission is granted.
        return;
      }
      MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[uris.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < uris.length; i++) {
        mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(uris[i], extensions[i]);
      }
      MediaSource mediaSource = mediaSources.length == 1 ? mediaSources[0]
              : new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
      player.prepare(mediaSource, !haveResumePosition, false);
      needRetrySource = false;
    }
  }

  private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri, String overrideExtension) {
    int type = TextUtils.isEmpty(overrideExtension) ? Util.inferContentType(uri)
            : Util.inferContentType("." + overrideExtension);
    switch (type) {
      case C.TYPE_SS:
        return new SsMediaSource(uri, buildDataSourceFactory(false),
                new DefaultSsChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), mainHandler, eventLogger);
      case C.TYPE_DASH:
        return new DashMediaSource(uri, buildDataSourceFactory(false),
                new DefaultDashChunkSource.Factory(mediaDataSourceFactory), mainHandler, eventLogger);
      case C.TYPE_OTHER:
        if (uri.getScheme().equals("rtmp")) {
          return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, rtmpDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
                  mainHandler, null);
        }
        else {
          return new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, mediaDataSourceFactory, new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
                  mainHandler, null);
        }
      default: {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unsupported type: " + type);
      }
    }
  }
```

Below error message i got
com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$UnexpectedLoaderException: Unexpected IllegalStateException: null

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Are you using Ant Media Server on media server side? Also, how can we reproduce this issue?